# How to save a image using ImageIO.write() in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, userappdatapath

I wanted to save image to user machine while he is launching my java application. for this i have written code as follows :

```
BufferedImage image = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(logourl);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);

            ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("/usr/swa.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it is giving me

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/swa.png (Permission denied)
```

but if i used

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("/home/MyUserName/Desktop/applicationName/logo.png"));
```

Then it saving the image.
i dont get why it is not accessing that path if it working for `/home/MyUserName/Desktop/applicationName/logo.png` this path.

basically when user install application i want fetch image from web url and save it to user's local machine so what i need to to achieve this??

EDIT : Exception  corrected

Comment: `/temp/applicationName/logo.png`? Did you mean  `/tmp/applicationName/logo.png`? Also, are you sure that this directory exists?

Comment: Given the error message I'd go for "/temp/applicationName does not exist" -- and in Linux that should be "/tmp"

Comment: yes this directory is exsits n i have tried like "/usr/local/" also but it giving me same exception.

Comment: Is this this my application not getting access to root ?

Comment: @SwapL That can't be happening. If the directory exists, it means that you don't have permissions to write to that directory. But java would fire a `java.lang.IOEsception: Permission Denied` in that case. So double check, likely your directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes Your right now i have just copied exact path the i got java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/swap.png (Permission denied)

Comment: @SwapL In that case you must run your application as root. But I would suggest that you choose a directory that doesn't require root access

Comment: @BackSlash i dont know which directory are dont require root access.

Comment: @SwapL AFAIK, Every directory under the `/home/yourUserName` directory should not require root access

Comment: Yes, but how i know there username ?

Comment: I don't know, but you should be able to find the user's home directory path with `String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");`

Comment: @BackSlash Yup Worked , thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have write permission to `/usr,` or, less probably, the file `/usr/swa.png` already exists and isn't deletable or writable by you.